# how to alter NSMutableArray in an specific array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray wich holds a Custom class of MKMapkit.

```
MapPoint *placeObject = [[MapPoint alloc] initWithTitle:title subtitle:subtitle coordinate:loc description:description storeImage:storeImage];
[annotationArray addObject:placeObject];
```

My routine fills the `placeObject` without the image because they will load asynchronously and finished after a couple of seconds. Now my questions is: Is there a way to alter the `placeObject` which is within the `annotationArray`?

**EDIT**

To display my issue in a better way here some code parts:

```
if (annotationArray == nil)
{
    [self setAnnotationArray:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
}
for (NSDictionary *locationDetails in parser.items)
{
    __block NSData *storeImageData;
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        storeImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:storeImageURL];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImage *storeImageTMP = [UIImage imageWithData:storeImageData];
            counterBlock ++;
            NSLog(@"async: %d", counterBlock);
            [imageArray addObject:storeImageTMP];
            });
        });
MapPoint *placeObject = [[MapPoint alloc] initWithTitle:title subtitle:subtitle coordinate:loc description:description storeImage:storeImage];
[annotationArray addObject:placeObject];
}
[mapView addAnnotations:annotationArray];
```

after this is done: `dispatch_queue_t` will start working. So I check every 2 seconds if its fully loaded. Then i start to alter annotationArray and refresh my annotations (remove all -> add to map witch additional image)

```
- (void) checkMap
{
    if (counterBlock == 547)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<=counterBlock; i++)
        {
            MapPoint *point = annotationArray[i];
            point.storeImage = imageArray[i];
        }
        if(timer)
        {
            [timer invalidate];
            timer = nil;
        }
        [mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];
        [mapView addAnnotations:annotationArray];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just alter it.  It's a pointer stored in the array, not a copy of the placeObject.  Whatever you do to the original will "appear" in the version accessed through the array (since they will be the same object).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is get a reference to one of the `MapPoint` objects in the array. Then you can set properties and/or call methods on the object as needed.

```
MapPoint *point = annotationArray[x]; // x is whatever index you need
point.image = ... // some image
```

Comment: Are you sure that `annotationArray` isn't `nil`?

Comment: I updatet my question `annotationArray` isn't `nil`, only the space for the Image

Comment: Did you use `@synthesize` and/or explicitly create your own ivar for the `annotationArray` property? It's possible the backing ivar is really `_annotationArray`. If you have a property then use it. Change everything to `self.annotationArray` to be sure.

Comment: `self.` effect nothing and `annotationArray` is synthesized

Comment: I found the issue: `imageArray` is `nil` in `checkMap` but why?

Comment: Do you ever allocate `imageArray`?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve from your mutable array, the object you want to alter with the `objectAtIndex` method

```
NSInteger indexofMyObject = 0;
MapPoint *point = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexofMyObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MapPoint instance placeObject is a pointer.  So adding it to the array does not copy placeObject by value, but actually holds its address.  Getting the address of the object from the array will allow you to manipulate it.

```
annotationArray[objectIndex].anything = anything you want
```